# Global search data table react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to create global search in my data , and go throughout all objects in data and update the state of the table. What is the best way to do this? In my state I receive data array, I've got two method to handle this behavior. Can not find what I mess? I try to use two method **handleSearch** and **handleSearchTest**

```
 const data = [
    { key: 1, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 1, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    { key: 2, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 2, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    { key: 3, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 3, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    { key: 5, deviceType: 'AccessPoint', deviceID: 4, name:'AP_2 ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'offline'},
    { key: 4, deviceType: 'AccessPoint', deviceID: 5, name:'AP_1', location: 'Room_104', status: 'offline'},
]


class EnhancedTable extends Component {
    state = {
        selected: [],
        data,
        order: {
            direction: 'asc',
            by: 'deviceID',
        },
        search: '',
    }

    handleSearch = (event, value) => {
        // debugger
        const {data} = this.state
        let filteredDatas = []
        filteredDatas = data.filter(e => {
            let mathedItems = Object.values(e)
            let returnedItems
            mathedItems.forEach(e => {
                const regex = new RegExp(event.target.value, 'gi')
                if (typeof e == 'string')
                    returnedItems = e.match(regex)
            })
            return returnedItems
        })
        this.setState({data: filteredDatas, search: event.target.value})
    }

    fuzzyContains = (text, search) => {
        if (!text)
            return false
        if (!search)
            return true

        search = search.toLowerCase()
        text = text.toString().toLowerCase()

        let previousLetterPosition = -1

        return search.split('').every(s => {
            previousLetterPosition = text.indexOf(s, previousLetterPosition + 1)

            return previousLetterPosition !== -1
        })
    }

    handleSearchTest = (e, search) => {
        const {data} = this.state

        let result = data.filter(x => Object.keys(x).some(key =>
            this.fuzzyContains(x[key], search)
        ))

        this.setState({data: result})
    }


    render = () => {

        const {selected, data, search, order} = this.state

        return (
            <Paper>
                <Table
                    data={data}
                    search={search}
                    onSearch={this.handleSearchTest}
                />
            </Paper>)
    }
}
export default EnhancedTable
```

Answer (score 0):

All I need is to create 2 dataset, one for original data and one for filtered data, and modify only filter data not original data.

```
state = {
        selected: [],
        data,
        filteredData: data,
        order: {
            direction: 'asc',
            by: 'deviceID',
        },
        search: '',
    }

fuzzyContains = (text, search) => {
        if (!text)
            return false
        if (!search)
            return true

        search = search.toLowerCase()
        text = text.toString().toLowerCase()

        let previousLetterPosition = -1

        return search.split('').every(s => {
            previousLetterPosition = text.indexOf(s, previousLetterPosition + 1)

            return previousLetterPosition !== -1
        })
    }

handleSearch = search => {
        const {data} = this.state

        let filteredData = data.filter(x => Object.keys(x).some(key =>

            this.fuzzyContains(x[key], search)

        ))

        this.setState({filteredData, search})
    }
```